# Original source on a result of convergence in measure and a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

A relatively well-known result in measure theory states that given a sequence $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of measurable functions from a $\sigma$-finite measure space $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ then the sequence $(f_n)$ convergences in measure to a function $f$ if and only *every* subsequence $(f_{n_m})$ has a subsequence $(f_{n_{m_p}})$ which converges to $f$ almost everywhere.

In fact, a part of the proof of this fact is presented in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262612/convergence-in-measure-and-almost-everywhere) post.

> By whom and where was this theorem originally proved?

Note: I am interested in sources, not the  proof, which people have already answered in MSE.

Comment: This site http://math.gmu.edu/~dwalnut/teach/Math776/Spring11/776s11lec11_notes.pdf credits half the theorem to Riesz.