# A characterization of convergence in a finite measure

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Below we use [Bochner measurability](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_measurable_function) and [Bochner integral](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_integral). Let

- $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a *complete finite* measure space,
- $(E, | \cdot |)$ a Banach space,
- $S (X)$ the space of $\mu$-simple functions from $X$ to $E$, and
- $L^0 (X)$ the space of $\mu$-measurable functions from $X$ to $E$.
- $L^1 (X)$ the space of $\mu$-integrable functions from $X$ to $E$.

We define
$$
\rho (f, g) := \int_X \min\{|f-g|, 1\} \, \mathrm d \mu
\quad \forall f, g \in L^0 (X).
$$

Then $\rho$ is a [pseudometric](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Pseudometric_space) on $L^0 (X)$ such that $\rho (f, g) = 0$ IFF $f=g$ a.e. I already [proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4753822/the-metric-space-l0-x-rho-of-mu-measurable-functions-is-complete) that $S (X)$ is dense in $L^0 (X)$ and that $L^0(X)$ is complete. I would like to verify below statement found in [this](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Convergence_in_measure#Properties) Wikipedia page, i.e.,

> $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ in $(L^0 (X), \rho)$ IFF for every $\varepsilon>0$
> $$
> \mu (\{x \in X : |f_n (x)-f(x)| > \varepsilon\}) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0.
> $$

Could you have a check on my below attempt? Thank you so much for your help!

---

WLOG, we assume $\mu$ is a probability measure. Then
$$
\mu (\{x \in X : |f_n (x)-f(x)| > \varepsilon\}) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0
\quad \forall \varepsilon>0,
$$
is precisely the [definition](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Convergence_of_random_variables#Definition_2) of $f_n \to f$ in probability. It remains to prove that $f_n \to f$ in probability IFF $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ in $(L^0 (X), \rho)$.

1. $\implies$

Assume $f_n \to f$ in probability. Let $(f_{n_k})$ be an arbitrary subsequence of $(f_n)$. Let $g_k := f_{n_k}$. Clearly, $g_{k} \to f$ in probability. It's well-known [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222264/another-question-on-almost-sure-and-convergence-in-probability) there is a subsequence $(g_{k_m})$ such that $g_{k_m} \xrightarrow{m \to \infty} f$ a.s. The claim then follows from below result, i.e.,

> [Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4753838/a-characterization-of-convergence-in-the-metric-space-l0-x-rho-of-mu) $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ in $(L^0 (X), \rho)$ IFF every subsequence has in turn a further subsequence that converges to $f$ a.e.

2. $\impliedby$

Assume $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ in $(L^0 (X), \rho)$. Fix $\varepsilon>0$ and let
$$
r_n := \mu (\{x \in X : |f_n (x)-f(x)| > \varepsilon\})
\quad \forall n \in \mathbb N.
$$

It suffices to prove $r_n \to 0$. Let $(f_{n_k})$ be an arbitrary subsequence of $(f_n)$. Let $g_k := f_{n_k}$. By above **Lemma**, there is a subsequence $(g_{k_m})$ such that $g_{k_m} \xrightarrow{m \to \infty} f$ a.s. It's well-known [that](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Proofs_of_convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_almost_surely_implies_convergence_in_probability) $g_{k_m} \xrightarrow{m \to \infty} f$ in probability and thus
$$
r_{n_{k_m}} \xrightarrow{m \to \infty} 0.
$$

To sum up, any subsequence of $(r_n)$ has a further subsequence that converges to $0$. [Then](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397978/every-subsequence-of-x-n-has-a-further-subsequence-which-converges-to-x-the) $(r_n)$ converges to $0$.