# The metric $\hat \rho (f, g) := \inf_{\delta >0} \{ \mu (|f - g| > \delta) +\delta \}$ on the space of $\mu$-measurable functions is complete

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, metric-spaces, measurable-functions, complete-spaces

Below we use [Bochner measurability](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_measurable_function) and [Bochner integral](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_integral). Let

- $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a *complete finite* measure space,
- $(E, | \cdot |)$ a Banach space,
- $S (X)$ the space of $\mu$-simple functions from $X$ to $E$, and
- $L^0 (X)$ the space of $\mu$-measurable functions from $X$ to $E$.
- $L^1 (X)$ the space of $\mu$-integrable functions from $X$ to $E$.

For simplicity, we write
$$
\mu (|f - g| > \delta) := \mu (\{x \in X : |f (x) - g(x)| > \delta\})
\quad \forall \delta >0.
$$

Notice that the completeness of $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ implies $\{x \in X : |f (x) - g(x)| > \delta\} \in \mathcal A$. We define
$$
\hat \rho (f, g) := \inf_{\delta >0} \{ \mu (|f - g| > \delta)  +\delta \}
\quad \forall f, g \in L^0 (X).
$$

I would like to verify that

> **Theorem** $(L^0 (X), \hat \rho)$ is complete.

Could you have a check on my below attempt? Thank you so much for your help!

---

First, we define another pseudometric $\rho$ on $L^0 (X)$ by
$$
\rho (f, g) := \int_X \min\{|f-g|, 1\} \, \mathrm d \mu
\quad \forall f, g \in L^0 (X).
$$

Then

> **Lemma**
>
> 1. $(L^0(Y), \rho)$ is complete and $S(X)$ is dense in $(L^0 (X), \rho)$.
> 2. The following statements are equivalent:
>
> - (S1) $\rho (f_n, f) \to 0$,
> - (S2) Every subsequence of $(f_n)$ has a further subsequence that converges to $f$ $\mu$-a.e.
> - (S3)  $f_n \to f$ in measure, i.e.,
>   $$
>   \mu (\{x \in X : |f_n (x)-f(x)| > \varepsilon\}) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0
>   \quad \forall \varepsilon>0,
>   $$
> - (S4) $\hat \rho (f_n, f) \to 0$.
>
> *Proof* The proof of the completeness of $\rho$ can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4753822/the-metric-space-l0-x-rho-of-mu-measurable-functions-is-complete). The proof of (S1) $\iff$ (S2) can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4753838/a-characterization-of-convergence-in-the-metric-space-l0-x-rho-of-mu). The proof of (S3) $\iff$ (S4) can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4754273/convergence-in-a-complete-finite-measure-is-metrizable). The proof of (S1) $\iff$ (S3) can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4753870/a-characterization-of-convergence-in-a-finite-measure).

It follows from above **Lemma** that $(L^0(Y), \rho)$ is complete and that $\rho, \hat \rho$ induce the same topology on $L^0 (X)$. Let $(f_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $(L^0 (X), \hat \rho)$. It suffices to prove that $(f_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(L^0 (X), \rho)$.

Fix $\varepsilon >0$. There is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that
$$
\hat \rho (f_n, f_m)  < \varepsilon
\quad \forall n > m \ge N.
$$

There is $\delta_{n, m} >0$ such that
$$
\mu (|f_n - f_m| > \delta_{n, m})  +\delta_{n, m} < \varepsilon
\quad \forall n >m \ge N.
$$

For all $n >m \ge N$, we have $\delta_{n, m} < \varepsilon$ and $\mu ( |f_n - f_m| > \varepsilon ) < \varepsilon$. For all $n >m \ge N$,
$$
\begin{align*}
\rho (f_n, f_m) &= \int_X \min\{|f_n-f_m|, 1\} \, \mathrm d \mu \\
&= \int_{\{|f_n - f_m| > \varepsilon\}} \min\{|f_n-f_m|, 1\} \, \mathrm d \mu + \int_{\{|f_n - f_m| \le \varepsilon\}} \min\{|f_n-f_m|, 1\} \, \mathrm d \mu \\
&\le \mu ( |f_n - f_m| > \varepsilon ) + \varepsilon \mu(X) \\
&\le \varepsilon + \varepsilon \mu(X) \\
&= (1 + \mu(X)) \varepsilon.
\end{align*}
$$

This completes the proof.